# How to get LinkedIn profile picture using OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, linkedin-api

Users can log in to my Rails app using their LinkedIn account thanks to OAuth. However, I am having trouble displaying the user's profile image. The following URL does not load a picture:

`<%= image_tag("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-url") %>`

How can I get the user's LinkedIn profile image to display in my Rails app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to get the original picture with:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-urls::(original)
```

**Update:**

From [current docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) (recommend to read it):

Using current user (after user logged in):

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)
```

Using member_id:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=12345:(picture-url)
```

Public profile:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=<public-profile-url>:(picture-url)
```

Those URLs return `xml`, so you could parse the `xml` response to get `picture-url` string and use it as a param for `image_tag`. Alternatively, you can retrieve info as a `json` passing an extra param like:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json
```

In both cases (`xml` or `json`), you need to extract the `picture-url` from api response for passing it to `image_tag`.

This gem `omniauth-linkedin-oauth2` could probably help you.

Comment: I updated the answer referencing current documentation. It worked?

Comment: Thanks for the update. How do I reference the user's member token? uid doesn't seem to be it

Comment: Just tried: `<%= image_tag("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id={user-id}:(picture-url)") %>` but still no luck

Comment: Thanks for the all of the additional info! So would I parse the URL in a model or a controller and then make that an instance variable to pass to the view? I'm not sure what the process is to parse and then pass that to the link in the view.

Comment: Yes, they are options. For example, use `@response = JSON.parse(open(url_with_json_format).read)` and you'll have a hash into `@response`. Then you can access attributes like `@response['person']['profile_url']`.

Comment: So close! I put `@response = JSON.parse(open('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json').read)` in my controller but now I get a 401 Unauthorized error `OpenURI::HTTPError in UsersController#show`. I don't understand why it's unauthorized since this is occurring after the user logs in. Any ideas?

Comment: Even after using the public profile URL, `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url={public-profile-url}:(picture-url)?format=JSON`, I still get the 401 error.

Comment: If you are using the gem, it's better to change approach to: in oauth callback save some (relevant) attributes from hash response to users table. One of them, the column `picture_url`, then you'll be able to use it like: `@user.picture_url`.

Comment: I think this is the way to go as well. Thanks for all of the help!!

Comment: No prob @james. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution working perfectly:

```
def callback(self):
    self.validate_oauth2callback()
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
        data={'code': request.args['code'],
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()},
        decoder=jsondecoder
    )
    me = oauth_session.get('people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))?format=json&oauth2_access_token='+str(oauth_session.access_token), data={'x-li-format': 'json'}, bearer_auth=False).json()
    social_id = 'linkedin$' + me['id']
    name = me['firstName']
    surname = me['lastName']
    email = me['emailAddress']
    url = me['publicProfileUrl']
    image_small = me.get('pictureUrl', None)
    image_large = me.get('pictureUrls', {}).get('values', [])[0]
    return social_id, name, surname, email, url, image_small, image_large, me
```